# AngularJS - $httpProvider Interceptor handling and modify response data

Tags: angularjs, http, response, interceptor

I want to use an interceptor for status code error handling. For example, when I'm loading an template through `$route` and I don't have the permission to do so I'm sending an 403 status code back from the server together with some html data, which I want to display instead of the originally requested template. Is this possible inside my interceptor in the 'responseError' function?

```
'responseError': function(rejection) {
  // do something on error EXAMPLE
  if (canRecover(rejection.htmlData)) {
    return responseOrNewPromise //here I want to add my server error html data and return that to the client instead of the originally requested data 
  }
  return $q.reject(rejection);
}
```

I know, that I could do a location.path change but i want to save the extra routing.

Comment: You can do `return $q.reject(ModifiedData);`

Comment: The problem is, that I return the error html data from the server in the same way as a normal response (http code 200) but nonetheless it isn't displayed to the client. Does $q.reject don't send the response data to the templateUrl method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [ngRoute docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24route):

> #### $routeChangeError
>
> Broadcasted if any of the resolve promises are rejected.

#### Add an event listener to when a promise resolve is rejected

```
app.run(function($rootScope){
   $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError',function(angularEvent,current,previous,rejection){

     // console.log(rejection)

   })
})
```

#### I also recommend these tutorials:

- https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-resolve-routechangeerror
- https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-directive-for-route-handling